# Making Nice Labels on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a google maps api way to display this exact kind of text label next to a marker? I know how to create the marker and a bad looking label, but I was hoping to create labels like the ones that appear on google maps already:

[image: Labels]

Montes Grill & Pub for instance, or is this some css/html/js stuff I have to do?

**Edit:** I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Google Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) gives your that option when you do a search.

Comment: That doesn't seem to allow me to add my own label though, just the one that Google already has for the location. I need to be able to modify the text on it.